# DataRow вместо конкретного объекта данных в программе

Tags: база-данных, архитектура, модель-данных

Всем доброго времени суток)

Знакомясь с устройством работы одной программы заметил, что в ней нет классов, которые бы отображали сущности объектов реального мира.

Поясню на примере. Допустим, у нас есть машина с конкретным набором параметров. Нам надо проверить эти параметры. В модели есть методы для проверки параметров, однако класса машины с набором параметров нет. Вместо этого из базы данных получаем конкретный DataRow и загружаем его в методы проверки параметров.

Вопрос: каковы преимущества и недостатки данного подхода? Для меня данный подход был весьма необычным. Я всегда считал, что в программе модель первична, а база данных является источником информации. Ведь объект DataRow по сути достаточно абстрактен. Необходимо знать названия столбцов в строке. К тому же, работая с программой, я не вижу конкретного класса Car с набором параметров. Одним словом, данные из DataRow сразу отображаются на экране или идут в методы для их проверки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы описываете это некоторая противоположность `ООП`. Концепции предметной области в коде явно не присутствуют, только в голове автора.

Плюсом является экономия на создании и проработке модели, что позволяет написать прототип быстрее.

Минусы данного подхода проявляются на длинных дистанциях и на кодовых базах сколько-нибудь значительных размеров. В основном, это сложность создания в голове нового программиста модели предметной области на основе кода или сложность сопоставления имеющейся модели с кодом. Что приводит к деградации кода, дублированию, спагетти-коду и отсутствию уверенности в том что и как 
именно работает и как далеко распространятся побочные эффекты от рефакторингов.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за развернутый ответ). Значит предчувствие меня не обмануло)